# Making a hole in a Dynatopo sculpt without Boolean

Tags: sculpting, dynamic-topology

I was just wondering if there are other ways of creating holes in meshes that aren't 100% symmetrical (thanks dyntopo) or too intricate using something other then the Boolean modifier.

I'm currently working on a skull for starters but I need a hole in the cheeks and it got me wondering about whether there are possibilities beyond the obvious.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60459/dyntopo-sculpting-how-to-carve-out-like-a-boolean-instead-of-push-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use a more advanced boolean solver. there's a plugin somewhere that uses the CarveMT solver to make more complex cuts

The biggest villain in boolean operations is that it comes to a point blender doesn't know how to deal with all the vertices and all the new geometry it has to create to accomodate the change, be it a union or a cut. If possible, decimating or reducing the mesh density in the area of the cut will increase the chances of success

Comment: Well it shouldn't be too hard to just merge some faces where you'd wanna do the boolean i think.